# Automatic Calculation Turned Off by VBA Macro

Tags: excel, vba, optimization, solver

I have the following code which is repeated several times in a larger Macro. I am finding that if I specify the *search method* (by including "Engine:=..") the macro turns off the *Automatic Calculation* (found in *Formulas>Calculation Options*) and switches it to manual. This essentially fixes the optimisation at a single point, even though the below optimisation is on a loop as it optimises to different values. As the cells that are linked to each other do not update because of this problem this renders the optimisation useless.

I can run the macro without specifying the search method but ideally I would like to be able to choose it. Any ideas?

```
SolverReset
    SolverOK SetCell:="$K$21", MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:="0", ByChange:="$D$41:$H$41", Engine:=2
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$K$25", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="1"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$D$41:$H$41", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$D$41:$H$41", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="$D$12:$H$12"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$D$41:$H$41", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="$D$13:$H$13"
                        SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
                        SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1
                        Range("K23").Value = Range("K21").Value
```

Comment: what version of Excel? This didn't happen on my testing in xl2010.

Comment: Agree with @brettdj. Are you sure you are not turning the calculation to manual anywhere else... for example `Worksheet_Change`

Comment: The code was originally written in Excel 2007 and run now in Excel 2010. I have been running the code effectively in 2010 for a few weeks now... until I added the Engine:= part.